# Strange Data View Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql

I am running a very simple query to extract data from _Open Data view along with Email Name.

```
select 
O.AccountID, O.OYBAccountID, O.JobID, O.BatchID, O.SubscriberID, O.EventDate, O.ListID, O.Domain, O.IsUnique, 
O.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, O.TriggeredSendCustomerKey, O.SubscriberKey, 
J.EmailName


from _open O
left join _job j on O.JobId = J.JobID
```

The results are ok but Some of records does not have email name, while TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID is also blank for those records, that means it wasn't even a part of Journey Builder send. Now when I went into _Job DE I found those JOBID's does not exist in _JOB data view. Then I went into AllSubscribers History tab and searched for subscriber and it shows me the email name and at what time email was open. So open time does match the records with _Open but email name is missing in data while email name is visible in AllSubscribers History tab and those jobIDs do not exist in _Job data view?

Any thought, what could be the reason here?

Comment: Were these sent over 6 months ago? Job only keeps records for 6 months. So if it was opened 5 months and 3 weeks ago, but sent over 6 months ago there would be an open record in open but nothing matching in job.

Comment: 6 months of data retention only applicable on Job data view or across all data views ?

Comment: If it were sent 6 months ago but Job data view does contains email from 2018 as well ?

Comment: The vast majority of Data Views are on a 6 month retention, including Job. (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5#shared) I think its only DV like Subscribers that have over a 6 month retention. I have verified the 6 month retention in a couple accounts I work in for Job, not sure how you are seeing emails sent over 6 months ago - perhaps you have a custom Business Rule enabled? If so, you will likely need to chat with Support to figure out what the issue could be.

Comment: _job dataview has only jobs that were modified in the past 6mths